# How to set metadata when posting via email in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, post, metadata

I have a custom post defined that includes an item of metadata (a URL). My Wordpress loop displays the title of the post and links to the URL - the content is not displayed.

Can anyone help me set up posting via e-mail in Wordpress such that the subject line is the title and the body is the URL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress provides a handy hook for posting via e-mail, `publish_phone`. Add this code into your **functions.php** in the active theme directory.

```
add_action('publish_phone', 'set_metadata');

function set_metadata($post_ID) {
    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $meta_key = 'url'; //the name of your metadata
    update_post_meta($post_ID, $meta_key, $content);
}
```

Comment: Hi Xiankai, so if I define the meta_key in this way, where in the e-mail that I'm sending to WP to post would I declare the metadata value? Note that per post the metadata is different.